# Loading react application in a jsp page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsp, antd

We have our main application page in jsp and we built another application in reactjs and needed to embed the react application in jsp page, main jsp page should get handle of the react form submit action and able to submit the form for validations and for actual submission.

Currently able to embed the react application using iframe ( which could be a security issue) in main jsp page iframe document.

Jsp Page loads body content via iframe -> inside this iframe document -> I am embedding react js application using another iframe.

But not able to do submit action from main jsp page, tried getting handle of iframe from window but nothing works, any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript (i.e. React) in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.