# React on select change option value of display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antd library as part of react application. For select option values are fetched from api and rendered in this format.

```
<Select
  {...propsForSelect}
> 
  {this.props.data.map(e => 
     <Option
        key={e.key || e}
        value={e.value || e}
        title={e.title}
      >
        {`${e.key} | ${e.value}`}  
      /Option>
    )}
</Select>
```

Once user selects an option I want to display only the value and not {`${e.key} | ${e.value}`} value. 
{`${e.key} | ${e.value}`} is displaying in dropdown and when user selects an option need to show e.value alone.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-feynman-uhtn7

Comment: can you share your complete code or in sandbox?

Comment: Can you please share `{...propsForSelect}`?

Comment: please find codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-feynman-uhtn7, let me whether sandbox is working

Comment: @Umair, we can ignore propsForSelect

Comment: @RinsenS Do you also want to change all the values (to just `e.value`) in the dropdown options or just the selected value?

Comment: @UmairSarfraz, i dont want to change all the dropdown values, when an option is selected eg: Action | 1000 , I am in need to display only 1000 instead of Action | 1000

Comment: @RinsenS Got it. Please see my answer that achieves exactly what you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-river-1n0e3

Basically I just added a `selected` property to each genre object, and then in the Select component's `onSelect()` prop, passed a callback function that updates state and toggles the respective genre's `selected` property to true.

Then, in the UI, I simply check if the `selected` property is true for each genre and then conditionally render only the `display` value in that case.

Comment: Once you selected, re-click the selection you would find that the options display also changed

Comment: I think I got it working now - https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-river-1n0e3

Comment: thank you ! if possible can you help on this one also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370845/loading-react-application-in-a-jsp-page

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [`optionLabelProp`](https://ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-option-label-prop) is for.

[image: Edit priceless-euler-9wuql]

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Select } from 'antd';

const { Option } = Select;


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    genres: [{"key": 1000, "value": "1", "display": "Action"},
    {"key": 1001, "value": "2", "display": "Adventure"},
    {"key": 1002, "value": "3", "display": "Comedy"}]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Select
          style={{width:"50%"}}
          optionLabelProp="value"
        >
        {this.state.genres.map(e => 
          <Option
            key={e.key}
            value={e.value}
          >
            {`${e.display} | ${e.value}`}
          </Option> 
        )}

        </Select>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

Comment: thank you ! if possible can u help on this one also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370845/loading-react-application-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: What if instead of displaying plaintext, you want to display a react node?

Comment: @Konrad I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean?

Comment: Instead of simply displaying text from the props, I was wondering if it was possible to display a react node, for instance instead of displaying e.value, we'd like to display <span>random text</span>

I've found out since I asked you, that you can pass a component as an arbitrary props such as contentRender to Option, then in Select set optionLabelProp="contentRender". It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    genres: [
      { key: 1000, value: "1", display: "Action" },
      { key: 1001, value: "2", display: "Adventure" },
      { key: 1002, value: "3", display: "Comedy" }
    ],
    selected: '' // A default value can be used here e.g., first element in genres
  };

  handleChange = key => {
    this.setState({ selected: this.state.genres.find((object) => object.key === Number(key)).value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Select value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChange} style={{ width: "50%" }}>
          {this.state.genres.map(e => (
            <Option key={e.key}>
              {`${e.display} | ${e.value}`}
            </Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```